# Convergence of $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dx$

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

I posed a question to my calculus professor, asking how to evaluate the Riemann integral

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) \, dx$$

I can simplify the above integral as

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\,dx = \int_{-\infty}^a f(x)\,dx + \int_a^\infty f(x)\,dx $$

$$\lim_{t\rightarrow -\infty} \int_t^c f(x) \, dx + \lim_{w\rightarrow \infty} \int_c^w f(x)\,dx$$

What happens if I get $ -\infty + \infty$ ?

My professor answered that we cre unable to know where the integral convergences. Is that really the case or not?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "*we [are] unable to know where the integral [converges]*".  Could you explain what this claim means?

Comment: I mean to find if the integral converges or diverges.

Comment: I see.  The way things are usually done, we would say that, in such an instance, the integral diverges rather than saying "it is impossible to tell whether it converges or diverges".

Comment: Can we answer if it has a value or not? No magic theorem out there to help? Except the Cauchy principal ^_^

Comment: If it diverges, then it doesn't have a value.  Sometimes we would say that integrals of the form $c + \infty$ or $c - \infty$ have a value of $\infty$ or $-\infty$, but even in this setting, integrals of the form $\infty - \infty$ have no value.  There are different methods for "regularizing" divergent integrals, e.g. using the Cauchy principal value or Hadamard regularization. "Regularization" means taking integrals that shouldn't have a value and giving them a value that "makes sense".  Different methods work for different settings, and they don't always give the same answers.

Answer (score 1):

For improper Riemann integrals where any of the limits involved are $\infty$, we say that the integral **does not converge**, or **diverges**.  So, for example, $\int_{-\infty}^\infty x\,dx$ does not converge since 
$\lim_{a \to \infty} \int_0^a x\,dx = \infty$ and since
$\lim_{b \to -\infty} \int_b^0 x\,dx = -\infty$.

Note in this case that we may evaluate the limit $\lim_{a \to \infty}\int_{-a}^a x\,dx = 0$.  Although the integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty x\,dx$ diverges, we state that its [Cauchy principal value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value) is $0$.

Comment: Personally, it would make sense to state that the improper Riemann integral diverges if I came up with $\infty + c = \infty$ or $-\infty + c = -\infty$ . $-\infty + \infty$ does not make any sense

Comment: Since the integral has no value that makes sense, we say that the integral diverges.  Just because an integral "diverges", doesn't mean that its value is somehow infinite. A related situation is that of the integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \cos(x)\,dx$.

Answer (score 1):

With the integral
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x}{x^2+1}\,dx
$$
you actually do get $-\infty+\infty$.  And
$$
\lim_{a\to\infty} \int_{-a}^a \frac{x}{x^2+1}\,dx =0. \tag 1
$$
And
$$
\lim_{a\to\infty} \int_{-a}^{2a} \frac{x}{x^2+1}\,dx = \log_e 2. \tag 2
$$

The value in $(1)$ is the "Cauchy principal value" of the improper integral.

It is only when the positive and negative parts are both infinite that rearranging like this can change the value of the integral.  Convergence like that in $(1)$, where the limit changes with a rearrangement because both the positive and negative parts are infinite, is called "conditional convergence".  When the positive and negative parts are both finite, then one has "absolute convergnce" and rearrangement will not change the value.